# deep leaning based on theano example error

Tags: python, out-of-memory

I am trying to run theano based python example from

http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/gettingstarted.html#

```
import cPickle, gzip
# Load the dataset

f = gzip.open('mnist.pkl.gz', 'rb')

train_set, valid_set, test_set = cPickle.load(f)

f.close()
```

I get error

> self.extrabuf = self.extrabuf[offset:] + data MemoryError

I understand this is a memory issue but I am working on CPU machine with 32gb of ram.

I don't really understand the error. Is that buff allocated in szlib is small to handle it, if so can I increase the memory allocation.

Comment: Can you include the real code and real errors in your question?

Comment: this is the real code. and i get memory error on my  machine .

Comment: "C:\Python27\lib\gzip.py", line 320, in _read   self._add_read_data( uncompress )
   "C:\Python27\lib\gzip.py", line 338, in _add_read_data  self.extrabuf = self.extrabuf[offset:] + data
MemoryError

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):  "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 601, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 66, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)
   "C:/new.py", line 6, in <module> train_set, valid_set, test_set = cPickle.load(f)
   "C:\Python27\lib\gzip.py", line 268, in read self._read(readsize)
   "C:\Python27\lib\gzip.py", line 320, in _read